# How to parse stack configuration string to EnumType struct in C# Pulumi Azure Native

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, pulumi

Trying to get resource arguments from stack settings file (`Pulumi.dev.yaml`) and use configuration values to create resource, for example StorageAccount. For `SkuName` & `Kind`, `readonly struct` is being used (why not enum???) and if those were `enum` type, I could easily parse from string (stack configuration string value) to enum using `Enum.Parse(EnumType, "stringValue")`.

**How to parse stack configuration string value to (EnumType) struct?**. Am I missing something? is there any better way to achieve that?

(.Net SDK uses ExpandableStringEnum: `ExpandableStringEnum<SkuName>` →
`SkuName`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this, at the moment. You'll have to fall back to reflection to make this work:

```csharp
public static T ParseEnum<T>(string value)
{
    return (T)typeof(T).GetProperty(value)?.GetValue(null);
}

// Usage example
var sku = ParseEnum<SkuName>("Standard_LRS");
```

An improvement is tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/7267), please upvote it.